# Best way to authenticate all requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a number of functions that are making calls to an api using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).  So a number of calls similar the one below (simplified for this example):

```
requests.get(url, data=data, auth=('user','password'))
```

All of the requests are going to be authenticated and I would like to find a cleaner way to authenticate all request rather than just including the `auth=('user','password')` portion in every call.

My first thought was to create a sub class that inherits from the `requests` class and then override the `get` function.  Something like below:

```
class authRequests(requests):
  def get(url, data):
    return requests.get(url, data=data, auth=('user', 'password'))
```

and then use `authRequests.get` instead of `requests.get`.  I don't have a ton python experience so this might not be a working example, but i'm wondering if this would be the right approach, or if I should be using a different method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to persist things across different requests:

> Sessions can also be used to provide default data to the request methods. This is done by providing data to the properties on a `Session` object

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.auth = ('user', 'password')

    session.get(url, data=data1)
    response = session.post(another_url, data=data2)
```

Comment: Ahh interesting - so if I have 15 functions that contain calls to `get` could I just wrap all the functions with the `with` statement?

Comment: @AbeMiessler yup, you don't have to use `with` context manager, can instantiate a session object and pass it around. If the functions are methods of the same class, you can instantiate the session as an instance attribute: `self.session = requests.Session()` and use it to make requests `self.session.get(url, data=data)`..hope that helps.